# how to make span element in middle of text in div

Tags: html, css

i have a code like bellow:

```
<div style="font-size:58px;"> Name <span style="font-size:18px; vertical-align:middle;">|</span> 2015-04-01 </div>
```

and then i have the result like this
[image: and the result like this]

but i want the span element a little bit higher like this
[image]

so please teach me how to do, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the `span` element technically is already in the middle. You can verify this by applying `vertical-align:top;`, `vertical-align:bottom;` or `vertical-align:middle;` on the `span` element.

Other than that, I’d recommend using

```
position:relative;
top:-.5em;
```

on the `span`. Use the `em` units to make it dependent on font size (although that doesn’t perfectly work because it’s dependent on the font size of the `span` element).

Demo:

```html
<div style="font-size:58px;"> Name <span style="font-size:18px; vertical-align:middle;position:relative;top:-.5em;">|</span> 2015-04-01 </div>
```

Of course you can adjust the value as you please.

Comment: you code is work very well. Thank you very much :)